# Need to know when my app send a notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app, that have a MainActivity(Mr.Obvious), a Service and a BroadcastReceiver. In my MainActivity I have an AlarmManager like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BroadReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

In my BroadcastReceiver I have this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
    context.startService(service1);
}
```

And in my service, I have this:

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker(getText(R.string.notification_ticker))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.green)
            .setContentTitle(frase())
            .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_text))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);}
```

I want my app to enable a button in MainActivity when the user receives a notification, it possible?

Comment: you can enable it from broadcast receiver itself right?

Comment: Create the object on broadcast, like on Main?

Comment: What about your app state in that scenario ? background or foreground or you need to work in both state ?

Comment: Both. That's why I need the Service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - If your in background start activity newly

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
in.putExtra("state", "background");
startActivity(in);
```

> - Get string extra then compare it and control the button
> - If your in foreground make button object as public then control it
> - Use a global variable to identify MainActivity in foreground or not(Using activity life cycle)

```
  onDistroy()


  onStart()
```

Comment: But if I do that, when the service send the notification the MainActivity will open right?

Comment: But if I do that it will be anoying because it will open the MainActivity all the time.

Comment: " I want my app to enable a button in MainActivity when the user receives a notification, it possible? " without opening the MainActivity how can you do so ?